# Show div with images using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok, so I am looking in multiple directories for images and want to display those images in a div depending on the selection from a dropdown.

Here is what I got...

PHP Code:

```
$random_dir = 'avatar/random';
$scan_random_dir = array_diff(scandir($random_dir), array('..', '.'));
$random_images = $scan_random_dir;

$christmas_dir = 'avatar/christmas';
$scan_christmas_dir = array_diff(scandir($christmas_dir), array('..', '.'));
$christmas_images = $scan_christmas_dir;
```

I know this can be done differently, but this is the only way I knew how.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.collection').hide();
        $('#random').show();
        $('#selectCollection').change(function () {
            $('.collection').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        })
    });
```

HTML & PHP to display all images:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="selectCollection">Choose a collection</label>               
                <select class="select select-block" name="selectCollection" id="selectCollection">
                    <option value="Random">Random</option>
                    <option value="Christmas">Christmas</option>
                    <option value="World">World</option>
                </select>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php foreach($random_images as $random_img) { ?>
                        <!-- display collection images in a DIV -->                             
                        <div id="random" class="col-md-2 collection"><a href="#" title="<?php echo $random_img; ?>"><img src="<?php echo "$random_dir/$random_img"; ?>" class="thumbnail img-responsive danger" /></a></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php foreach($christmas_images as $chistmas_img) { ?>
                        <!-- display collection images in a DIV -->                             
                        <div id="christmas" class="col-md-2 collection"><a href="#" title="<?php echo $chistmas_img; ?>"><img src="<?php echo "$christmas_dir/$chistmas_img"; ?>" class="thumbnail img-responsive danger" /></a></div>
                        <?php } ?>                      
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
```

EDIT: I was not paying attention to what I was doing. I was loading the script before the jquery. It now works, but only displays 1 image from each folder. Any Ideas?

When I inspect the element it shows only the first image being set with a style of `display: block` the rest are set to 'display: block'. Not sure why this is happening or how I can fix.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It may be due to the fact that you've used double quotes in your HTML and embedded PHP, causing the HTML to load incorrectly and display all of the `.collection` items. Try only using single quotes in your HTML, some things in PHP will work different to how you suspect with single quotes!

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the value of your options. All values are with the first letter in Uppercase. Maybe "Random" should be "random".

```
<select class="select select-block" name="selectCollection" id="selectCollection">
    <option value="random">Random</option>
    <option value="christmas">Christmas</option>
    <option value="world">World</option>
</select>
```

Anyway, i have a functional example here: http://jsfiddle.net/svbz0L3j/2/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. I had to use a class instead of an id.

Here are the changes to my code...

In the HTML I added another class for each div:

```
<div id="random" class="col-md-2 collection random">
<div id="christmas" class="col-md-2 collection christmas">
```

And then changed the JS to this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.collection').hide();
        $('.random').show();
        $('#selectCollection').change(function () {
            $('.collection').hide();
            $('.'+$(this).val()).show();                
        })
    });
</script>
```

Using a class instead of an id seem to do the trick. Being that I am using a foreach loop all of the id's are the same therefore it would only output the first img in the directory because id's should be unique.